# How to deploy a mean.js web app to heroku, with the database hosted at mlab?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose, mlab

Please tell me the exact step by step instructions. Suppose I just newly cloned and built my new [MEAN.JS](https://github.com/meanjs/mean) application. It is running fine on my localhost.

And now I have created a new database at mlabs. Got the URI, user and passkey for that database from mlabs.

Now please tell me how to proceed to successfully deploy this application on heroku.

---

What I've tried : ---

I changed the production.js file, even the development.js file located in the env folder.

Ive done this in those two files. After doing this, when I run the app on my localhost, it successfully runs and the database gets connected to mLabs. But in heroku, it gives an application error. I am also including the heroku logs.

```
  db: {
uri: "mongodb://xxx:mLabxxx@ds023624.mlab.com:23624/project",
options: {
  user: 'username',
  pass: 'password'
},
// Enable mongoose debug mode
debug: process.env.MONGODB_DEBUG || false
```

}

[HEROKU LOGS](https://gist.github.com/karunk/9bd3e75123ab7e7c2977358f886af2fc)

According to the logs, i think it is not able to connect to the database. See this error : --

```
 [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
```

Comment: In some place you try to connect in localhost? The error indicate as the application doesn't are trying to connect to mLab, and yes 127.0.0.1:27017. Help if you share the connect block of code.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku runs your app on production environment as default, so you should check the production configuration.

Taking the repository you linked as a base, in [this line](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/fb9d9d912cc905c2a7ada426a432dcf6b7462851/config/env/production.js#L16) it gets the DB url from environment variables called `MONGOHQ_URL` or `MONGODB_URI`, so you should either [add them to Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#setting-up-config-vars-for-a-deployed-application) with the MongoLab URI or replace on the code with the variable name you want (make sure it is created on Heroku too).

If it works on your localhost and not in Heroku, it means that the production config is wrong on Heroku, you should also make sure you are pushing the changes to the production config file to Heroku repository too. If you want to test on Heroku using the development environment, you can change [this setting](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#runtime-behavior).